AxiosError "Request failed with status code 500"
When I trigger submitForm an error appears
500 (Internal Server Error)
{message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
this is my ajax code
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: _this.apiUrl,
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        _this.libary = JSON.parse(data);
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });

this is my submitForm code
            submitForm(event, id) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const _this = this;
                var actionUrl = ! this.editStatus ? this.actionUrl : this.actionUrl+'/'+id;
                axios.post(actionUrl, new FormData($(event.target)[0])).then(response => {
                    $('#modal-default').modal('hide');
                    _this.table.ajax.reload();
                });
            }

does anyone know how to fix it?

Hi ! It's a 500 error, so it's a problem from the application you're calling. If you want help with that, please provide the backend code

Yes, check the server logs not a VueJS issue. Also why do you even use jQuery with Vue?? Use Vue's API + axios or fetch, why having both mixed up??

axios.post(actionUrl, new FormData($(event.target)[0])).then(response => {
The code don't have the headers as the same of the ajax.
Add the headers after the new FormData($(event.target)[0]), it will be an object, like { header: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': YOUR VALUE} }
